# XeTeX giving option clash error

Tags: xetex, color

I'm trying to clear a maddening error from this `.tex` file:

```
%
% Syllabus template for use with http://kjhealy.github.com/latex-custom-kjh
%
\documentclass[11pt,article,oneside]{memoir}

%% Script-based version control (requires vc package)
% \input{vc}

\usepackage{graphicx,url}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{memoir-article-styles} % in latex-custom-kjh/needs-memoir

%% Choose font system. Comment out these lines if you are not using xelatex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}

% Biblatex
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,
            bibstyle=authoryear,
            citestyle=authoryear-comp,
            uniquename=false,
            hyperref=true,
            backend=biber, babel=hyphen, bibencoding=inputenc]{biblatex}

%% Fix biblatex's odd preference for using In: by default.
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{%
  \printtext{\bibstring{}\intitlepunct}}}

%% Bibliography from http://kjhealy.github.com/socbibs/
\addbibresource{/Users/kjhealy/Documents/bibs/socbib.bib}

% Definitions
\def\myauthor{Kieran Healy}
\def\mytitle{Sociology 155: Organizations and Management}
\def\mysubtitle{Syllabus}
\def\mycopyright{\myauthor}
\def\mykeywords{}
\def\mybibliostyle{plain}
\def\mybibliocommand{}
\def\mysubtitle{}
\def\myaddress{276 Soc/Psych}
\def\myemail{kjhealy@soc.duke.edu}
\def\myweb{http://www.kieranhealy.org}
\def\myphone{660-5737}
\def\myaffiliation{\ \\Duke University}
\def\mykeywords{Sociology, Syllabus, Undergraduate, Organizations, Management}

%% Links
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[xetex,
colorlinks=true,
urlcolor=BrickRed,
plainpages=false,
   pdfpagelabels,
   bookmarksnumbered,
   pdftitle={\mytitle},
   pdfauthor={\myauthor},
   pdfkeywords={\mykeywords}
   ]{hyperref}

%% Uncomment to make a "DRAFT" watermark
% Page watermark
% \usepackage{type1cm,eso-pic}
% \makeatletter
% \AddToShipoutPicture{%
% \setlength{\@tempdimb}{.5\paperwidth}%
% \setlength{\@tempdimc}{.5\paperheight}%
% \setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}%
% \put(\strip@pt\@tempdimb,\strip@pt\@tempdimc){%
% \makebox(0,0){\rotatebox{45}{\textcolor[gray]{0.9}%
% {\fontsize{3cm}{3cm}\selectfont{Draft Only}}}}%
% Marginal Watermark
% \makebox(-100,-300){\rotatebox{45}{\textcolor[gray]{0.95}%
% {\fontsize{2cm}{2cm}\selectfont{}}}}
% \makebox(-500,-0){\rotatebox{90}{\textcolor[gray]{0.95}%
% {\fontsize{0.7cm}{0.7cm}\selectfont{}}}}
% }%
% }
% \makeatother

\begin{document}

%%% xelatex font choices
%\defaultfontfeatures{}
%\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
% You will need to buy these fonts, change the names to fonts you own, or comment out if not using xelatex.
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Myriad Pro}
\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-text,Scale=0.8]{Pragmata}

%% blank label items; hanging bibs for text
%% Custom hanging indent for vita items
\def\ind{\hangindent=1 true cm\hangafter=1 \noindent}
\def\labelitemi{$\cdot$}
%\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{~}

% Make figures as wide as the margins
\setkeys{Gin}{width=1\textwidth}

\chapterstyle{article-2} % alternative styles are defined in latex-custom-kjh/needs-memoir/. Consider e.g.\chapterstyle{article-4}
\pagestyle{kjh}

\title{\mytitle}
\author{\myauthor\smallskip\footnotesize\newline Office: 276 Sociology/Psychology \newline\texttt{\myemail} \newline \url{http://www.kieranhealy.org}}
\date{}

\published{\sffamily Spring 2010 / Tu\&Th 1:15--2:30pm / Gray 228}

\maketitle

% Include version information in footer if using vc package (see above).
% \thispagestyle{kjhgit}


% Copyright Page
% \textcopyright{} \mycopyright


%
% Main Content
%

\section{Course Description and Objectives}

%\newpage
%% Uncomment if you want a printed bibliography.
%\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
/home/larry/Desktop/kjhealy-latex-custom-kjh-f5ba457/templates/basic/.syllabus.t
ex.swp:53: LaTeX Error: Option clash for package color.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.53 \usepackage
                [xetex,
No pages of output.
Transcript written on /tmp/.syllabus.tex.log.
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: See [this FAQ entry (`optionclash`)](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=optionclash).

Answer (score 6):

LaTeX only loads a package once. In case of further `\usepackage` or `\RequirePackage` commands for an already loaded package, LaTeX only checks the options and complains, if it sees any new option that was not present, when the package was loaded.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}% might be hidden in a package
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

LaTeX complains with the "option clash" error message. Pressing "h" reveals the details:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package color.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4 \begin
          {document}
? h
The package color has already been loaded with options:
  []
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [usenames,dvipsnames]
Adding the global options:
  ,usenames,dvipsnames
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
?
```

### Global options

The help text also offers a workaround, putting the options to the global options. However, then they are seen by other packages that might not be the best choice, considering option names such as `draft`. Therefore I would use global options as last resort, if the next methods fail.

### Earlier loading with all options

If the package loading order does not matter, then the package can be loaded at an earlier stage with all options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
% ...
\usepackage{color}% might be hidden in a package
% ...
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
% ...
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{color}
```

### `\PassOptionsToPackage`

Often the package loading is not explicit, but hidden inside other packages or even classes. Then `\PassOptionsToPackage` helps that also can be used *before* `\documentclass`:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{color}
\documentclass{...}
...
```

Comment: The \PassOptionsToPackage command did the trick. I would have never figured that out on my own. Thank you...